# SSIS Script Task- Updated Excel

Tags: ssis

I need to Updated a Specific cell in Excel in a server,but that server is not having Microsoft office.
So how to update excel using Script task in SSIS 2008R2 ?

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: Show us what have you tried...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post that appears detail just what you want to do: [Updating a single Excel cell using SSIS](http://bidn.com/blogs/KeithHyer/bidn-blog/2475/updating-a-single-excel-cell-using-ssis)